# Displaying a '+' character in the URL in the address bar

Tags: java, url

I am constructing a redirection URL in which one of the query parameters may contain a '+' sign. For example, the name of the provider may be 'John+Hancock'.

The problem is, even when I do not encode any query parameters, the '+' character appears encoded. I do not want this, since that particular parameter conveys important information. Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Thank!

Comment: Conveys what kind of important information? The `+` character in an URL is a space (`%20` can also be used). If you want an actual plus sign that's not to be interpreted as a space, you need to encode it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on it a bit more?

Comment: Not really. If you see an URL with a `+` in it, it's a space. URLs can't have spaces, so `+` (or `%20`) is used.